# Directive firing before ng-include resolved

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-include

I wrote a directive to focus on the first input in a dynamic form. I am using ng-include to include the HTML file containing the form inputs. When the app initially loads the focus is not working. If I navigate to other pages it works fine. After some research, I have figured out the inputs HTML has not yet been loaded when the directive is executed.

My current solution is to use $timeout and set the delay to 750 ms. Is there a better way to delay the directive until the HTML has finished loading? I'm not a big fan of setting the delay to a seemingly arbitrary value.  I have also tried ng-cloak, thinking maybe it would cloak the directive until the ng-include was resolved, but it didn't work.

Directive code:

```
angular.module('focusInput-directive', [])
    .directive('focusInput', ['$timeout', function( $timeout ) {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            link: function (scope, element) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    var field = element[0][0];
                    field.focus();
                }, 750);
            }
        }
    }]);
```

This directive is on my form, and the ng-include is within the form HTML.

Thanks!

Comment: Is your directive in the html that also has `ng-include` directive?

Comment: Also if you are open to use html5 you could just use `autofocus` attribute on the element.

Comment: I just edited to add "This directive is on my form, and the ng-include is within the form HTML.".  Not sure if you saw that or not. Does it answer your question?

Comment: @PSL I can't use autofocus because my form is dynamic. They are not coded into the page. I have an ng-repeat that renders the inputs.

Comment: your directive is created alongside the `ng-include`. You can listen to `$includeContentLoaded` event that `ng-include` fires, but this will make it less general.